# Toplink & java storing word or pdf files

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, toplink

I'm creating a simple page with a form.  Part of the form requires uploading a pdf or word document. This will be a small file, so ideally I would like to store it in my oracle database.

I'm using ejb and toplink for all of my persistence. What object should my entity class have that will hold a word or pdf file, and how do I map it to toplink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Can toplink map BLOB data](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/technical/tl10g_faq.htm#MappingBlobs). In terms of what type your entity should use, it's either `byte[]` or a serializable type apparently.